# Get Texture2D from a Canvas in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to post an image of my game hero to facebook. So I instantiate the prefab which contains number of UI elements, icons and texts.

I'd like to get a Texture2D or image data from it so I could send that as a payload to my facebook plugin.

If it was visible in camera and it wasn't a UI element I would get its texture from the camera, if I let it appear on the screen the full screen camera won't be looking at it, because it is rendered using canvas. Also canvas is also looking at other objects around it because this prefab doesn't occupy full screen.

Comment: Did you try [`Application.CaptureScreenshot`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.CaptureScreenshot.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong but I don't think that you can render the UI on a texture. It doesn't seem ideal, but you could use [CaptureScreenshot](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.CaptureScreenshot.html), then load the image and cut the part you want based on the resolution of Screen.